# How to write a R code for determining a value is above a line or below a line?

Tags: r

I want to write a R code as follows:

Give a function say y = xb + c where b and c are constants. 
I want to determine a horizontal interval say (alpha, beta) lies above the function, below the function or intersect the function. (See uploaded plot) [image: Plot of the function and line]

I find myself cannot figure out how to code this programming in R.

Would someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention that you also need to specify a y value for the horizontal range, which I assume in my answer.  A given horizontal range intersects the line `y = xb + c` if `y(x.min)` is *below* the y value of the line, and `y(x_max)` is *above* the y value of the line.  Here `x.min` is the start of the range and `x.max` is the end of the range.

```
intersect <- function(x.min, x.max, y, b, c) {
    y.min <- x.min * b + c
    y.max <- x.max * b + c

    if (y.min <= y & y.max >= y) {
        print("intersection")
    }
    else if (y > y.min) {
        print("above")
    }
    else {
        print("below")
    }
}
```

**Note:**

This answer assumes that the line has a positive slope.  If the line also might have a negative slope, then there is a second criteria for intersection, so the `if` statement would look like this:

```
if ((y.min <= y & y.max >= y) | (y.min >= y & y.max <= y)) {
    print("intersection")
}
```

Comment: @alistaire I'll make the update now, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Your solution is incomplete because there is also an intersection if `y.min > y & y.max < y` and if any one of them is equal to y.  You also have a small error in `y.max <- y.max * b + c`, which should be: `y.max <- x.max * b + c`.

Comment: @R.Schifini I fixed the formula typo.  With regard to the other type of intersection, I have assumed that the function is monotonically increasing, as in the image, which means only one criteria needs to be checked.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, change all inequalities to >= and <=, because if the segment ends touch the straight line is also an intersection.